# How can I only allow LAN requests that aren't secure in Swift iOS14

Tags: swift, xcode, plist, ios14

I've been searching the internet and still cannot find an answer.

My app talks to other smart home products within the home. For example, it can make requests to the Philips Hue Bridge to control the lights via POST requests. The IP of my bridge is `192.168.0.12`. I am making a POST request to this endpoint, however it isn't allowed as the connection is unsecure.

I still want to keep the setting of where external connections to domains are secure since I connect to my own server via a domain, which is secure. So I only want to allow local connections via local IP addresses to be unsecure.

I have tried this:

[image]

Yet it doesn't work. I've even tried using `Allow Arbitrary Loads` just for testing to see if it would work, and it still wouldn't.

My API call:

```
func getPhilipsHueUsername(completion: @escaping (String?, Error?) -> Void){
    var bridgeIP = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "bridgeIP")
    let url = "http://" + bridgeIP! + "/api"
    var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
    request.httpMethod = HTTPMethod.post.rawValue
    let body = [
        "devicetype": "test"
    ]
    do {
        let dataToS = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: body, options: .fragmentsAllowed)
        request.httpBody = dataToS
    }catch{
        print("Error creating data object")
        return
    }
    AF.request(request).responseJSON { (response) in
        switch response.result {
        case .success(let value):
            print(value)
            if(response != nil){
                let json = JSON(value)
                print(value)
            }
            return completion("",nil)
        case .failure(let error):
            return completion(nil, error)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post the code for your api call?  I'm not having any issues connecting to local devices by IP

Comment: @valosip sure, just added them, sorry for late reply

Comment: @valosip maybe because I'm using Alamofire?